# WooCommerce Checkout add default value to Billing fields if custom checkbox checked

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

I've already created a custom checkbox field in the checkout page with a  name of **billng_anonymouse**, now I want when a customer checks this checkbox it should add a default value to **billing_first_name** and **billing_last_name**.

currently, I'm using this function to add a default value for billing fields

```
function zk_set_checkout_field_input_value_default($fields) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['default'] = 'First';
    $fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['default'] = 'Last';
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'zk_set_checkout_field_input_value_default' );
```

but the problem is the default values are always there, how to show them using an IF function only if the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `custom_attributes` in `woocommerce_checkout_fields` so you have a value stored in attribute to use on checkbox check and uncheck. try the below code.

```
function zk_set_checkout_field_input_value_default($fields) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'data-default' => 'First' );
    $fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['custom_attributes'] = array('data-default'=>'Last' );
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'zk_set_checkout_field_input_value_default' );

function add_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) { 
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $billng_anonymouse = $current_user->billng_anonymouse;
    woocommerce_form_field( 'billng_anonymouse', array(        
        'type'  => 'checkbox',        
        'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),        
        'label' => 'Billng anonymouse'
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'billng_anonymouse' ) ); 
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', 'add_custom_checkout_field' );

function add_custom_js(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $(document).on('change', '#billng_anonymouse', function(event) {
                if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
                    $('#billing_first_name').val($('#billing_first_name').data('default'));
                    $('#billing_last_name').val($('#billing_last_name').data('default'));
                }else{
                    $('#billing_first_name').val('');
                    $('#billing_last_name').val('');
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'add_custom_js', 10, 1 );
```

Tested and works.

[image]